# Oracle: Activate DBLINK before transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dblink

Consider two systems: A(source system) and B(recipient system)
We are having a stored Oracle procedure to upload some details from A to B. We are having a DBLINK to insert data from A to B.
We are getting a DBLINK error

> ORA-01012: not logged on
>   ORA-02063: preceding line from A_B_DBLINKORA-06512

As per my understanding if a DBLINK is inactive for more than 30 mins (as configured in system B), and system A makes an attempt to connect to B, it throws this error.

To solve this we are thinking to approach it as below:

```
UPLOAD PROCEDURE
begin
if A_B_DBLINK='Active' then
    enter procedure;
    upload data;
else
    //attempt to trigger DBLINK as active
    //calling UPLOAD PROCEDURE
end;
```

I need help to implement this, I am currently using `select * from dual@A_B_DBLINK;` to test if connection is active, but can't trigger it active(unable to test the fail scenario).
Kindly, guide me a way forward.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find anything about the closure of inactive db links in the documentation?

Comment: I've never seen this error even though I use db links, so I don't think it's as simple as not using it within 30 min. How are you using the db links?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
   v_my_value        NUMBER := NULL;
   v_dblink_status   VARCHAR2 (10) := 'INACTIVE';
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (1) INTO v_my_value FROM DUAL@A_B_DBLINK;

   v_dblink_status := 'ACTIVE';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      BEGIN
         v_dblink_status := 'INACTIVE';
      END;
END;
```

Comment: At the end of this PL/SQL block, you have in any case populated the variable v_dblink_status.  If DBLink works, you have v_dblink_status = 'ACTIVE'.  If DBLink doesn't work, you have v_dblink_status = 'INACTIVE'.

Comment: if the dblink is 'INACTIVE', will it come under exception block or will it return nothing in the query.

Comment: If the SELECT statement fails, you jump into the EXCEPTION block, case "OTHERS" (any type of fault): in this case you set v_dblink_status = 'INACTIVE'.

Comment: If the SELECT statement succeeds, you set v_dblink_status = 'ACTIVE' ignoring the EXCEPTION block.

Comment: Thanks will test this approach... although, if v_dblink_status='INACTIVE', is there any way to trigger an external system B to get it active?

Comment: The DBLINK may be unusable for various reasons.  Wrong username and/or password you use in the dblink, wrong S.I.D., remote server unreachable (i.e. somebody has decided for a shutdown of the remote server avoiding to notify your team).  So there isn't a general way to activate the DBLINK: it depends on WHAT TYPE of fault you have.  For example, if the Administrator of the remote server makes a joke changing the access password, you can no more obtain access although you want it.  You have only the right to create, modify and delete your DBLink, but you aren't always able to solve the faults